# Flexslider width and space between images

Tags: html, css

I recently downloaded Flexslider and managed to extend the images, and I have two things I need help with. The first thing is that I want the slider to be full width, and apparently it is being blocked from that in `.container` by `overflow:hidden`. If I remove that piece of code, everything expands and the website doesn't look right, but it removes the space between the slider and the screen. Does anyone know how I can fix that?

And my second question is how I make a small space between the slider images. Here is an example of how I want it: [Example](https://cdn2.cdnme.se/2037638/8-3/1_567973b92a6b2297b6d70041.png)

Here are my codes:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kx5/431/)

Comment: Ok managed to get spaces between the images but I still need to do something about the space between the slider and the screen

Comment: Not sure if I get you right but try adding margin:0px on the body to see if that works for you.

Comment: Oh god, was it that easy lol! Thank you so much Stefan =)

Comment: You're welcome, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin:0px;` on the `body` fixes the problem.